# What is the point of async Accept() in socket programming if WaitOne() blocks anyway? See example

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, tcp, blocking

This example from Microsoft revolves around asynchronous socket programming. However, when it calls the asynchronous function BeginAccept, it then hits WaitOne() which waits for the BeginAccept to finish anyway.

```
    // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.  
    try {  
        listener.Bind(localEndPoint);  
        listener.Listen(100);  

        while (true) {  
            // Set the event to nonsignaled state.  
            allDone.Reset();  

            // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.  
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");  
            listener.BeginAccept(   
                new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),  
                listener );  

            // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.  
            allDone.WaitOne();  
        }  

    } catch (Exception e) {  
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());  
    }  

    Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");  
    Console.Read();  
}
```

What is the point of using the non blocking version of Accept when you essentially get blocked immediately anyway? How can I modify this version to allow me to do other things until the BeginAccept runs the callback function? I'm brand new to C# so I am super lost. I come from C and would probably handle this by just forking the listener.

EDIT: Here is the example

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example

Comment: You're right, it seems. The point of the async version is to relinquish the thread for other use, but then it blocks anyway on the wait, so...

Comment: You need the block so the program doesn't terminate.  If you use the non blocking version of accept you will only be able to have one client connect to the server.  The non blocking will allow many users from different IP address to connect to the same listener.  The Listener every time a new client connects create a new socket for each connection.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks! I had a feeling it was something like this, but my issue still stands. Do I just throw this entire listener in a seperate thread from the main part of the application if I need to continue doing things?

Comment: You can do what you want to be done asynchronously with `AcceptCallback` by inserting your code before  `allDone.WaitOne();` which is just blocking your thread until `AcceptCallback` being called.

Comment: No.  You just have to make sure the program doesn't terminate.  The accept is an Asynchronous Event and will continue to accept more clients until the listener is disposed or the program terminates.  You can put code into a class and once the constructor is called in the class will do the blocking.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks again for the response. My issue is that this is part of a large GUI app and it only starts listening after a button press. Even with the async sockets, the GUI stops updating.

Comment: If you have a GUI then you should be able to remove the WaitOne..  If you still have an issue use on the VS debug window Break All and find out where in code you are blocking.